# Enable PostgreSQL password login in pg_hba.conf grammatically

Tags: bash, postgresql

I'm using a library that only supports password authenticated login to psql. So solve this I've edited the `pg_hba.conf` file as per [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

I have a scripted install of my app and psql, and would like to enable local password login problematically from this bash script. Is there a more clever way than using `sed` or something similar? It sounds a bit "hackish" to alter the config and restarting the service.

Comment: Hi. Are you looking to login with cmd on a local machine (assuming that you are logged in on Linux)?

Comment: Aside: if you really are using PostgreSQL 9.1 (since it is in the link you provide), you should really try to upgrade...

Comment: If you have a scripted install of your application and PostgreSQL, why can't you ship your PostgreSQL install with a specific `pg_hab.conf` that is already formatted the way you need it for your application/library connecting to it? No need to change it afterwards.

Comment: They are not always compatible with all versions of PSQL DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a task for a decent config management implementing idempotent actions.

For example [ansible](https://www.ansible.com) has a module called [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html) for this particular job.

I'm not sure whether it's the best solution to directly edit file `pg_hba.conf`. Maybe you want to create the database and explicitly add users with the [ansible modules for Postgresql](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/list_of_database_modules.html#postgresql).

Implementing *ansible* just for this requirement might seem a bit heavy-weight but your question heads in a direction of automating things anyway.